=if(sum(N3,P3),sum(N3,P3), "") showing blank not zero
I am trying to make a gradebook in Google Sheets that tracks my Kindergarteners' scores by standards. The following formula shows blank when there are zeros in the N3 and P3 columns. I want it to show zero if there is a zero but blank if the columns are blank.
=if(sum(N3,P3),sum(N3,P3), "")

The "" shows blank even if there are 0s in the column, so I tried changing it to "0" but then it showed 0 when the columns were blank.
I also tried adding =0 after the first sum but that didn't provide the desired results either.
My purpose is to show 0 if they got the question wrong and blank if they haven't yet taken the test.

Try:
=IF(OR(N3="",P3=""),,N3+P3)

For an array of non contiguous cells, use:
=LET(r,{N3,P3},IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(r="")),,SUM(r)))


That works!!!! But is there a quicker way to do it if there are more than just two cells to add?

are the cells adjacent?

They are all horizontally in the same row but are not consistently next to each other.

That works perfectly!  Thanks so much for your patience and help!
